# Ubuntu 14.04 does not start

Tags: boot, 14.04

I installed successfully the latest version 14.04. But booting it, it tells it has found serious errors in hard-drive? And tells to push <kbd>i</kbd>,<kbd>s</kbd>,or <kbd>m</kbd> to get on, but nothing helps. Otherwise the PC works allright. What is wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem with 14.04.. It is not hardware problem.

Comment: Any idea to solve this problem ? I intend to go back to 12.04 vers.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hardware issue IE; your HDD is toast, try again after replacing.

Comment: sounds like but as you see it may not be : " I have the same problem with 14.04.. It is not hardware problem. –  nikyns 11 hours ago
 
add comment ??

Comment: Try testing the drive with manufacturers test utility. You will need to make bootable medium.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.. You need to select 'e' to edit when it displays the Ubuntu boot menu.  Look for the line which starts with linux and change the word which says "ro" to "rw" in that line. Then press F10 to boot... You can then make this change permanent by editing /boot/grub/grub.cfg after taking a backup of it.